# When testcases are uploaded to run in CircleCi pipeline, it shows "Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded

Tags: rspec, circleci, circleci-workflows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chd8o.png)

CircleCI shows Too long with no output (exceeded 20m0s): context deadline exceeded Error when test is uploaded

I have rerun the tets cases but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this happens when you run your tests and they don’t close connections opened to servers/sockets etc. Could you provide more details about the type of tests you have written?
But it’s worth checking the few Items:

When running tests locally do you see they finished running with following message?
[image]

- If Yes then the issue could be related to circle ci config
- If No then your tests might be missing connection close to the server etc. It was the case with me and identified it when ran all describes one by one locally.

My Issue was:
I had created a server instance in my `before` block but didn’t close it `after` the tests end

```
before(async () => {
  server = new MockServer();
  server.init(9004);
});
after(async () => {
  server.close(); // was missing this line
});
```

I hope it helps! If not you then maybe someone else!!